# Moving a Sub and maintaining correct scope (replacing Me.)

Tags: vba, excel, scope

I have a Sub within my application that is currently located within a userform called FRMPFC_folderCreatorWindow. For clarity of the overall application I wish to move this Sub from the userform into a Module called PFC_filesystemManipulation and call the Sub from there via a button in FRMPFC_folderCreatorWindow however, when I do this and run my code, an error is generated at the line:

```
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
```

I understand that this is because the Sub has been taken outside of the context of the form however, how do I maintain context without using Me.Controls? I'm guessing I need to reference the form and use FRMPFC_folderCreatorWindow.Controls but as most of the controls are nested within frames I'm unsure whether my current code acts upon the form or just the frame within which the button is located. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub PFC_createFolders(Basepath, currentControl, parentFolder, parentGroup)

Dim cCont As Control
Dim createSubFolder As String
Dim fs As Object

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Check if the project folder already exists and if so, raise an error and exit
    MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder

    'Create the superceded documents folder in every 2nd generation folder
    MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & "_Old versions"
    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
            If cCont.GroupName = parentGroup Then
                If cCont.Value = True Then
                    If cCont.Name <> currentControl Then
                        createSubFolder = cCont.Caption
                        NewFolder = Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder
                        If fs.folderexists(NewFolder) Then
                            'do nothing
                        Else
                            'Create 3rd generation folder
                            MkDir NewFolder

                            'Create the superceded documents folder in every 3rd generation folder
                            MkDir NewFolder & "\" & "_Old versions"

                            'Create hard-coded subfolders within Confirmit Exports
                            If createSubFolder = "Confirmit Exports" Then
                                MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder & "\Triple S"
                                MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder & "\Word Export"
                                MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder & "\Survey Definition"
                                MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder & "\Data"
                                MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder & "\Data" & "\" & "Early Data"
                                MkDir Basepath & "\" & parentFolder & "\" & createSubFolder & "\Data" & "\" & "Final Data"
                            End If

                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next cCont

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just experimented with this and replacing the Me.Controls with the following code works:

```
    FRMPFC_folderCreatorWindow.Controls
```

Comment: I deleted my reply, instead I'll add in comment: Me refers to the object self; when exporting the code to a separate module you explicitly need to define the object name to which you refer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's very confusing getting used to the scope of VBA and userforms coming from PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: No problem. In other languages they have similar keywords referring to the same principle: I think in Javascript and PHP they call it "This".

Comment: In informative addition it may be worthful to mention that a userform acts quite like a class module. In this sense you can instantiate a userform module eg set frmForm = new Usrform1 and create multiple objects of the same form class.

Comment: The implication of @KimGysen last comment is that referring solely to `FRMPFC_folderCreatorWindow.Controls` while multiple instances are open will probably not produce the results you are expecting. I've dealt with this by keeping a dictionary (key = window handle, item = window) of all the open instances in a public module elsewhere. then whenever you need to act upon one `FRMPFC_folderCreatorWindow` and not another you can use the Handle.